# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read the page at position error in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, h2

I faced following error in Intellij data base console when queries are being ran:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read the page at position
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply I changed `H2` dependency version as following and now every query run.

```
 <version>1.4.199</version>
```